# Are there any problems using Dragon NaturallySpeaking in a VirtualBox Windows guest, Linux host?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, thinkpad, dragon-naturally-speaking

I would like to set up Dragon NaturallySpeaking on a Windows XP guest, on an Ubuntu Linux host.

Will this work? Are there any issues that I should be aware of?

Thinkpad T61p
Ubuntu 9.10 host
Windows XP guest
VirtualBox 3.1.4

Comment: Think it'll be better if you frame the question as "Are there any problems using Dragon NaturallySpeaking in a VirtualBox Windows guest, Linux host" and then post your experience as an answer

Comment: That's not a question, right ?

Comment: I had the following issue with Windows as host, Linux as guest: [How I can get Dragon NaturallySpeaking to talk into my Linux virtual machine with VMware?](http://superuser.com/q/697622/116475)

Answer (score 3):

Here are some issues that arise (1 - 3 are mine, 4 and 5 from OP)

1. On Ubuntu Linux 9.04: I found that it is necessary to allocate *at least* 2GB of ram to the Windows Guest when running XP or Windows 7, but I have had not had similar success with Windows Vista.
2. Connecting a microphone was a challenge on Ubuntu <= 9.04 and a Dell XPS 1330; my resolution was to use an microphone with usb input.
3. Performance is flawless on my new Windows 7 guest / Ubuntu 11.10 host with 4GB of 8 total allocated to the guest.
4. Upgrading to Virtualbox 3.1.4 or later

   - earlier versions of virtualbox had a nasty bug in which audio input was choppy, however, issue was resolved in the latest version. (from OP)
5. " your processor speed is not adequate"

   - If you get this error when trying to install Dragon, you should ensure that your CPU frequency scaling is set to performance, rather than on demand. To do this, right-click on your panel, add to panel, and choose CPU frequency scaling Monitor, then just select performance. This should ensure that your processor is running full speed.